# Type error when using existential types Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am having an experiment with Existential Types in Haskell. I am building a very short Json library and am trying to construct a fold.
I am getting error in the code that uses the `forall` quantifier!

```hs
class (Show m) => JsonValue m

instance JsonValue Int
instance JsonValue Double
instance JsonValue String
instance JsonValue Bool

data Json = JObject [(String, Json)]
          | JArray [Json]
          | forall a . (JsonValue a) => JValue a

foldJ :: ([(String, b)] -> b) -> ([b] -> b) -> forall a . (JsonValue a) => (a -> b) -> Json -> b
foldJ object array value (JObject xs) = object $ map (bimap id (foldJ object array value)) xs
foldJ object array value (JArray xs)  = array $ map (foldJ object array value) xs
foldJ object array value (JValue x)   = value x -- ERROR HERE
```

I am using `-XExistentialTypes -XFlexibleInstances -XRank2Types`

The error looks like this:

```
Json.hs:335:47: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘a1’
      ‘a1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        a pattern with constructor:
          JValue :: forall a. JsonValue a => a -> Json,
        in an equation for ‘foldJ’
        at Json.hs:335:27-34
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          foldJ :: ([(String, b)] -> b)
                   -> ([b] -> b) -> forall a. JsonValue a => (a -> b) -> Json -> b
        at Json.hs:(333,1)-(335,47)
    • In the first argument of ‘value’, namely ‘x’
      In the expression: value x
      In an equation for ‘foldJ’:
          foldJ object array value (JValue x) = value x
    • Relevant bindings include
        x :: a1 (bound at Json.hs:335:34)
        value :: a -> b (bound at Json.hs:335:20)
    |
335 | foldJ object array value (JValue x)   = value x
    |                                               ^
Failed, one module loaded.
```

This is really confusing me. Ive used typed holes and everything *seems* like it is the correct type but when I put it together nothing works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always, signatures are parsed right-associative, i.e. it is

```
foldJ :: ([(String, b)] -> b)
         -> ( ([b] -> b)
              -> ( ∀ a . (JsonValue a)
                      => (a -> b) -> (Json -> b)
                 )
            )
```

Not that the ∀ quantifies over the *result* of the second application. It is thus in covariant position, meaning that whoever uses the function gets to pick what type `a` is. In fact your signature is equivalent to

```
foldJ :: JsonValue a
  => ([(String, b)] -> b) -> ([b] -> b) -> (a -> b) -> (Json -> b)
```

But that's not what you want to express: the caller can't pick the type, because it's hidden in the json structure!

What you actually want is to have the quantor only run over the `a -> b` *argument*, i.e. the caller has to provide an argument *that works for any type* `a`.

```
foldJ :: ([(String, b)] -> b)
         -> ( ([b] -> b)
              -> ( (∀ a . (JsonValue a) => (a -> b))
                    -> (Json -> b)
                 )
            )
```